# SQL. Get SUM where value is MAX

Tags: sql, sum, max

i have got a select:

```
select deptno,12*month+year,salvalue 
from career join salary on career.empno = salary.empno 
and startdate<=to_date('01-'||to_CHAR(month)||'-'||to_CHAR(year),'dd-mm-yyyy') 
and (
      enddate>=to_date('01-'||to_CHAR(month)||'-'||to_CHAR(year),'dd-mm-yyyy') 
      or enddate is null
    )
```

it's result is:

```
+---------+----------------+----------+
| deptno  | 12*month+year  | salvalue |
+---------+----------------+----------+
| 30      | 2067           |     3601 |
| 30      | 2091           |     3671 |
| 30      | 2091           |     3531 |
| 40      | 2032           |     1938 |
| 40      | 2044           |     1988 |
| 10      | 2106           |     8117 |
| 10      | 2118           |     8117 |
| 10      | 2130           |     8217 |
+---------+----------------+----------+
```

I need to get deptno where sum of salvalues in maximum 12*month+year is maximum.
in this table deptno is 10:

deptno = 30 max(12month+year) = 2091 sum(salvalue) = 3671+3531 = 7202

deptno = 40 max(12month+year) = 2044 sum(salvalue) = 1988

deptno = 10 max(12month+year) = 2130 sum(salvalue) = 8217

Comment: Which database version, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try along

```
WITH
MaxSalarySum AS (
  SELECT
    deptNo
    , twelveMonthsPlusYear
    , SUM(salValue) salValueSum
  FROM (
    select deptno, 12*month+year twelveMonthsPlusYear, salvalue 
    from career join salary on career.empno = salary.empno 
    and startdate<=to_date('01-'||to_CHAR(month)||'-'||to_CHAR(year),'dd-mm-yyyy') 
    and (
          enddate>=to_date('01-'||to_CHAR(month)||'-'||to_CHAR(year),'dd-mm-yyyy') 
          or enddate is null
        )
  )
  GROUP BY deptNo, twelveMonthsPlusYear
)
SELECT
  deptNo
FROM MaxSalarySum
WHERE salValueSum = (SELECT MAX(salValueSum) FROM MaxSalarySum)
;
```

Not especially elegant - but fairly generic.
See (based on the intermediate result) in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03486/5/0)

Please comment if and as adjustment / more detail is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a outer query grouping by `deptno`. Something like

```
SELECT deptno
FROM
(
select deptno,
12*month+year as computed_column,
salvalue 
from career join salary on career.empno = salary.empno 
and startdate<=to_date('01-'||to_CHAR(month)||'-'||to_CHAR(year),'dd-mm-yyyy') 
and (
      enddate>=to_date('01-'||to_CHAR(month)||'-'||to_CHAR(year),'dd-mm-yyyy') 
      or enddate is null
    )
) tab
GROUP BY deptno
HAVING SUM(salvalue) = MAX(computed_column);
```

Comment: HAVING SUM(salvalue) = MAX(computed_column); - it's incorrect

Comment: yes, I think you haven't understand what I want. for each deptno I need to find sum of salvalues where 12*month+year is maximum for this deptno. than I need to get deptno where this sum is max. There is example after table in my first post